# How to fetch data of multiple users in one query in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

i have a collection of user data.

```
UserCollection = [{
"Name":"User1",
"Age":24,
"Gender":"Male"},{
"Name":"User2",
"Age":25,
"Gender":"Male"},{
"Name":"User3",
"Age":26,
"Gender":"Female"}]
```

i need to find details of User1 and User2 with one query.
currently i am doing this in python...

```
list = ["User1","User2"]
for user in list:
  data = db.UserCollection.find({"Name":user})
  for userData in data:
     list2.append(userData)
```

Comment: use $in in find query instead of for user in list loop; as data=db.UserCollection.find({"Name":{$in:list}})

Comment: Thanks..it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure why you wanna do this as it is not a very generic approach and you could hit a snag down the road but just to solve your current issue try the following:

```
 db.UserCollection.find( { name: { $in: [ "User1", "User2" ] } } )
```